# Add a Google Map into a jquery ui tab

Tags: jquery-ui, google-maps, jquery-ui-tabs

I have to add a Map into a tab, but doesnt work:

http://jsfiddle.net/QLMQH/14/

Someone has suggested me to do this:
http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#...my_slider.2C_Google_Map.2C_sIFR_etc._not_work_when_placed_in_a_hidden_.28inactive.29_tab.3F

But i get resizeMap(); doesnt exist, any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`resizeMap()` is yesterday's code. Call `google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize')`!

[It works.](http://jsfiddle.net/QLMQH/25/)